# SQL Server 2014, Volumes in Resource Governor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, resource-governor

I'm looking at Resource Governor on 2014 and how it relates to volumes.  I can see where to set up MAX|MIN IOPS PER VOLUME on a resource pool.  That's not keyed by volume, however sys.dm_resource_governor_resource_pool_volumes is.  Should I read that as the pool's definition applies to every volume but the DMV reports what actually happened on each?

My understanding is this: say I have three volumes - E, F and G. I set min = 10, max = 300 on the pool.  Then there can be, at most, 300 IOPS against each drive for a max of 900 for the pool. The DMV shows what IO actually happened for each volume.  If the table/filegroup definition were such that the majority of the activity happened on one volume (let's say F) the numbers from the DMV would show large `read_bytes_total` and `write_bytes_total` for that volume and smaller numbers for the others.  Is this a correct understanding?

Neither BoL nor any of the blogs I've read make this explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to assume, per the documentation and indeed the names of the parameters themselves, that `MIN_IOPS_PER_VOLUME` and `MAX_IOPS_PER_VOLUME` control the maximum quantity of I/Os per second *per volume*.

i.e. as in your question, if you have three volumes in the resource pool, and set `MAX_IOPS_PER_VOLUME` to 300, then you'd have a maximum *total* IOPS of 900.

Without source-code-level access to SQL Server, it's impossible to say *for certain* if that's how it actually works, however the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-resource-pool-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) says (emphasis mine):

> MINIMUM_IOPS_PER_SECOND:
> Specifies the minimum I/O operations per second (IOPS) **per disk volume** to allow for the resource pool.
>
> MAXIMUM_IOPS_PER_SECOND:
> Specifies the maximum I/O operations per second (IOPS) **per disk volume** to allow for the resource pool.